# instanciar clase para acceder a propiedades desde otra clase SWIFT

Tags: swift, swift3, class

miren tengo tiempo buscando como instanciar clase para acceder a las propiedades... he visto por todos lados que hacen esto...

```
  let vc = otroViewController()
  vc.label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black // por ejemplo una etiqueta para cambiar su fondo
```

tambien he hecho esto pero es lo mismo obviamente:

```
 var vc: otroViewController? = nil // incluso sin usar nil
```

y en viewdidload

```
 viewDidLoad() {

  vc = OtroViewController() // tambien "otroViewController.self"
                                  y     "self.otroViewController"
 }
```

pero al hacer esto:

```
  let vc = otroViewController()
```

se esta creando un Viewcontroller NUEVO...y por lo tanto las propiedades no son las que necesito llamar, y no he podido llamar dichas propiedades de la clase para acceder a ellas y obtener los datos de esa clase.

Comment: Son muchas preguntas. Puedes enfocar un solo problema para que te puedan ayudar con la respuesta?  No te olvides de marcar una de las respuestas como solución si es que la hay.

Comment: olvide actualizar mi pregunta, ya quedo resuelta. saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de los SEGUES, son utiles para pasar datos entre diferentes Views:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
        //Checar a que view controller se esta llamando por medio del identificador del segue
        if segue.identifier == “segue_identificador_controller”
        {
            if let destino = segue.destination as? ViewController2
            {
                //Pasar los datos
                destino.label.text = “Ejemplo”
            }
        }

}

//Para invocar al nuevo View controlar
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: “segue_identificador_controller", sender: nil)
```

Y ya con esas funciones podrias trabajar sin problemas.

Comment: interesante.. este metodo tambien funciona si no estoy usando storybards?

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacer esto que a mi me funciona.

Primero llamas al storyboard donde esta el viewController que quieres acceder:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nombre del archivo storyBoard", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

Luego llamas al viewController del storyBoard casteandolo con la clase donde has definido vistas, variables, funciones, etc.:

```
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Lo que has puesto en Storyboard ID") as? ClaseViewController()
```

[image: inspector de atributos xCode 11]

He ocultado los campos de la imagen por temas de trabajo (es una captura de mi trabajo y no puedo mostrar información)

Haciendo esto puedes hacer:

```
viewController.label
```

ó

```
viewController.miFuncion()
```

etc.

Si no casteas el viewController no podrás acceder a sus vistas, parámetros o métodos

Comment: ok.. excelente, aunque ya hace mucho que encontré la solución, olvide que había preguntado aquí, lo que hago ahora es el uso de delegados, o protocolos incluso con programación reactiva con el uso de callbacks, o singletons, pero no tenia conocimiento de ninguno de ellos, aun así agradesco tu comentario ese método on storyboard también funciona. Gracias!